# Selecting polygon features that are not fully contained against neighbors in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

In QGIS what would be the best method to select features that are not fully contained against it's neighbours?

For example I want to select local authorities that have a coastline so in the example below how would you select the ones highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Obviously you could manually select them but this can be time consuming on larger datasets and is prone to error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a shapefile of the coastline then great, skip to *Step 3* otherwise:

1. Use **Dissolve** your polygon shapefile.
2. Use **Polygons to lines** on the output of *Step 1*.
3. Use **Select by location** and choose the relevant options such as selecting your original polygon layer to select the features from and the output of *Step 2* to use as the intersection layer. Use the geometric predicate `touches` which means it should select all polygons which touch the coastline:

   [image: Result]